# Битрикс Фотогалерея 2.0

Tags: веб-программирование, php, cms, битрикс

Как снизить качество выводимого фото в фотогалерее 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то для снижения качества фото, можно поступить следующим образом, в шаблоне фотогалереи жать фотографии при помощи функции [CFile::ResizeImageGet](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/resizeimageget.php), функция кеширует сжатые картинки и при повторных вызовах просто забирает картинку из кеша, не создавая дополнительной нагрузки на сервер.